# Importing nodes in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been following [a link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#Creating_the_Eclipse_project_files) to import my project directory.

I'm having a problem with importing node/directory which resides in the `/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_kinect/`. In particular, I'm skipping directly to step number 3 which is "Importing the project into Eclipse". I can reach up to the "File --> Import --> Existing projects into workspace" step, but I am stuck at clicking finish(it doesn't allow though..). The reason I jump straightaway to step 3 because I've already have galileo version of eclipse long time ago installed. Another thing is that, other nodes that reside in my home directory, are easily imported.

Any ideas?

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10825/importing-nodes-in-eclipse/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you're trying to import directories as though they were projects. You'll need to generate the .project files using the directions in step 2

Make sure you have your ros environment setup ( with the relevant "`. setup`" ) and issue a

```
    make eclipse-project
```

in the *package* directory (i.e. it won't work in a stack directory).

If you get an error it's likely that either

- you're trying in the wrong directory
- you don't have your environment set up and so cmake can't find the relevant rules supplied by ros to make the eclipse projects.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-05**:
@Asomerville: Not at all.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-08-05**:
@Patrick: I hope you don't mind my edit to your answer.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-08-04**:
So, am I right to say that it's doable with the apt-get installation instead of version control as "Asomerville" pointed out?

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-08-04**:
@alfa, not sure, but it would be unrelated. If you can't resolve/keep having that issue, it would be appropriate to ask in a separate post.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-08-04**:
Installing via svn, results in one error..huhu..error => svn co http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect': 200 OK (http://www.ros.org), what's that?

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-08-04**:
@Patrick, just delete the comments and put the info in your answer since it's relevant : ) @alfa looks like cmake cant find ros, make sure you have your ros environment setup since cmake will try to reach into ros to find rules to make eclipse-project.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-04**:
.. (argh, comment limit!) .. you should be grabbing it from version control, not using the one installed by apt-get. End comment. :)

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-04**:
Silly comment limit.. Anyway I think you have another problem though; that directory is probably read-only (you installed openni_kinect via apt-get, right?). make eclipse-project will want to write a .project file in that directory and that won't work. If you actually want to hack on openni_kinect..

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-04**:
I'm not an expert on the Eclipse integration stuff but if I'm not mistaken you can only create an Eclipse project from a ROS package, not a ROS stack. The directory you mention in your question (/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_kinect/) is a stack diretory..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-08-04**:
In step 2, there is a command "make eclipse-project", but I got an error saying "make: *** No rule to make target `eclipse-project'.  Stop." Any thoughts?